# Change directories in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS WSL

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In "Windows 10", You can install "Ubuntu 18.01 LTS" app from "Microsoft Store" and run it in `CMD` so you can use `bash`. Since this is not a native "Windows 10" feature, how can I navigate `My computer` using `bash` in this setup?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just a clarification, Ubuntu does not run in `CMD`. It runs under an host process named `wslhost.exe` which in turn is lauched by `wsl.exe`, the former providing the glue between linux ABI and Windows.

Also, visually the thing you call `CMD` is instead `conhost.exe` which provides the terminal emulator window for your bash console.

Again, there is no such thing as `My Computer`, it is just a commodity for exploring the root of your system.

Sorry for bothering, but it is vital to have a grasp of these differences when you start messing around with a *NIX system.

Anyway the answer is:

`cd /mnt/c`

or

`cd /mnt/d`

Answer (score 3):

1- Open `CMD` and run command: `bash`.

2- Check the current working directory by using command: `pwd`.

3- The output will be something like this: `/mnt/c/Users/YOUR_DESKTOP_USER_NAME`.

This is your "Users" folder found in C drive.

4- Use command `cd /mnt` then command `ls`. The output will be the available drives on your computer. For example: `c d e`.

5- You can then navigate to the C or D drives just by using the 'cd' command.